# Creating search feature, why is this "Warning: Division by zero in /path/test.php on line 29 Query was empty"

Tags: php, mysql, division, zero

I building a simple search feature that checks against a column "desc" in mysql table "products"

This is my code for the results, where `$find` is the user input string that has been formatted to uppercase.

```
 $dataQuery = 'SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE upper(`desc`) LIKE'%$find%'';
 $data = mysql_query($dataQuery) or die(mysql_error());

 //And we display the results 
 $pageContent = '';
 while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 $pageContent .= '
 <p>Desc:'.$result['desc'].' Price:'.$result['price1'].'</p>
 ';
 }
```

Why am I getting the following error:

```
Warning: Division by zero in /path_to/test.php on line 29

Warning: Division by zero in /path_to/test.php on line 29
Query was empty
```

Line 29 is this line:

```
$dataQuery = 'SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE upper(`desc`) LIKE'%$find%'';
```

This query produces results in php myadmin, but when used in my script it gives the error.

Does anyone have any ideas on this?

EDIT:

Here is the full script with db connection info removed:

```
<?php

//This is only displayed if they have submitted the form 
if ($searching == 'yes') 
{ 
$pageContent .= '<h2>Results</h2>'; 

//If they did not enter a search term we give them an error 
if ($find == '') 
{ 
$pageContent .= '<p>You forgot to enter a search term</p>'; 
exit; 
} 

// Otherwise we connect to our Database 
$bccConn   = mysql_connect($bccHost, $bccUser, $bccPass) or exit(mysql_error());
             mysql_select_db($bccDB, $bccConn) or exit(mysql_error());

 // We preform a bit of filtering 
 $find = strtoupper($find); 
 $find = strip_tags($find); 
 $find = trim ($find); 

 //Now we search for our search term, in the field the user specified 
 $dataQuery = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE upper(`desc`) LIKE'%$find%'";
 $data = mysql_query($dataQuery) or die(mysql_error());

 //And we display the results 
 $pageContent = '';
 while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 $pageContent .= '
 <p>Desc:'.$result['desc'].' Price:'.$result['price1'].'</p>
 ';
 } 

 //This counts the number or results - and if there wasn't any it gives them a little message explaining that 
 $anymatches=mysql_num_rows($data); 
 if ($anymatches == 0) 
 {
$pageContent .= '
 <p>Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query</p>
 ';
 } 

 //And we remind them what they searched for 
$pageContent .= '
 <p><b>Searched For:</b>  '.$find.'</p>
 ';
 } 

ob_start();
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/config.php';
require_once($docRoot . '/includes/layout.php');

$pageContent = '
<h2>orders</h2>
<form name="search" method="post" action="'.$PHP_SELF.'">
<p>Seach for: <input type="text" name="find" />
<input type="hidden" name="searching" value="yes" />
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" /></p>
</form>
';

echo $head1 . $pageDetails . $head2 . $header . $menu . $belowMenu . $content . $pageContent . $footer . $pageScripts;
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are improperly nesting your quotes.

Try:

```
$dataQuery = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE upper(`desc`) LIKE'%$find%'";
```

Single quotes will not expand your `$find` variable, and in fact the single quotes are terminated just after the `LIKE` leading PHP to evaluate % as the modulus operator.

Comment: Alright, that removes the error, but the page does not seem to progress. It appears when the user clicks search, the page refreshes?

Comment: Are you setting the `$searching` variable somewhere and just removed it?  (For example, `$searching = $_REQUEST['searching']`)

Comment: $searching is a hidden form value, when the user clicks search, $searching becomes true, then the if searching = true declaration starts the actual search.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, PHP does not implicitly create the `$searching` variable for you, you must read it from the request.  Also, you are overwriting `$pageContent` outside of the `if` block after building the interface.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're terminating the string with the quote before %$find%. Perhaps it's trying to perform a modulus with $find and if $find is non-numeric it'd be trying to mod by an integer value of zero.